# What does this regular expression mean?

Tags: regex

could somebody please tell me what the following expressions means:

```
\d{6,8}
```

As far as I know it's a regular exp

Comment: I suggest to have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between 6 and 8 numeric digits.

(As it's not anchored to boundaries or start & end of string, it would also match between 6 and 8 digits within a longer series of digits - for instance, it will match `123456`, `1234567`, `1234678`, but also the first 8 digits of `123456789`.)

`\d` is a character class - it could also have been written as `[0-9]`.  The `{}` part is a repetition count; it could be a single number, e.g. `{6}`, or, as in this case, a range - so the `{6,8}` means "the previous thing, repeated between 6 and 8 times".

Answer (score 2):

it matches between 6 and 8 sequential numeric digits.

`\d` is equivalent to the character class `[0-9]`, and the `{,}` notation specifies an exact number of times that a pattern has to match.

Answer (score 1):

matches a digit that is of length between 6 and 8

Answer (score 1):

it means, at least 6 digits and no more than 8 digits

Answer (score 1):

It means between 6 to 8 numbers in a row.

- \d means a number [0-9]
- {6, 8} means min. of 6, max. of 8

You use curly braces to describe how many of the previous character you want to look for. Entering a single number, like {3} means 3 in a row. Adding a second number changes this into min/max.

http://www.regular-expressions.info
 is the best site on the web for learning about regular expressions.