# Regular Expression to Replace Unwanted Letters

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote a small program in C# to Capture ingame Text.
My issue is that the Text allso containts Collor Codes which i try to not to have. I read about the function [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Which i think is going to suite for that.

I have Following String (Line) i want to clear i used the small little tool espresso to play a little bit with regular expression but i never figured it really out.

This is the String i am going to work with:

```
|c001177ffSave Code =|r |cff00AA00A|cff00AA00G|cff00AA00Q|cffff69b4g|r |cff00AA00R|cff40e0d09|cffffff00$|cffffff00#|r |cff40e0d04|cffff69b4f|cff00AA00R
```

I try to use `^|( [a-zA-Z0-9]{9})`

which gave me theese matches
`c001177ff
cff00AA00
cff00AA00
cff00AA00
cffff69b4
cff00AA00
cff40e0d0
cffffff00
cffffff00
cff40e0d0
cffff69b4
cff00AA00`

Well i am not good at regex more likly i just started it. I don't want any body to present me completed solution (you are more than welcome to do that) at least a little help how i can solve that issue. I want to filter the Text.

Inpute Code

```
 |c001177ffSave Code =|r |cff00AA00A|cff00AA00G|cff00AA00Q|cffff69b4g|r |cff00AA00R|cff40e0d09|cffffff00$|cffffff00#|r |cff40e0d04|cffff69b4f|cff00AA00R
```

Should be Filtered to this

```
Save Code = AGQg R9$# 4fR
```

I think theese are Hexadecimal Color Codes the |c marks the beginning and the |r the End of the string.I think the |r | is just used to indicate that the first color string ends than we get an SPACE and the | indicates the next start.

Comment: does `string.Split('|')` + a few lines of code not work? Do you have to use Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem you were having was not escaping your `|`... the following regex works for me:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(intput, @"\|c[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}|\|r", "");
```

- `\|c[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}` - match starting with `"|c"` and then any 8 letters or numbers
- `|` - or
- `\|r` - match `"|r"`

Comment: This defently was one of the Problems Thank you i keep that in mind that i have to escape | if i look for it

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple Linq?

```
var output = String.Join("", input.Split('|')
                             .Select(s => s.Length != 10 ? ' ' : s.Last()))
             .Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Your regex

```
^|( [a-zA-Z0-9]{9})
```

Both forces the match to be only at the start of your input string, due to the [`^` start-of-line anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411), and the `|` needs to be escaped, because unescaped, it's a special ["or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22187948), which completely changes the meaning of your regex.

In addition, the space after the `|` is undesired, and the [capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) is unnecessary, as you only want to eliminate this portion.

If you replace all instances of this

```
\|[a-zA-z0-9]{9}
```

with *nothing* (the empty string)

You will achieve *most* of your goal. Try it here: http://regex101.com/r/rF6yB6/1

But it seems you really want to eliminate not just *nine* characters after the pipe, but *up through nine* characters. So use the [`{1,9}` range quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17032985) instead:

```
\|[a-zA-z0-9]{1,9}
```

Try it: http://regex101.com/r/rF6yB6/2

This seems to achieve your goal exactly.

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "[The example input from your question]";
string output = input.Replace("|r", "");
while (output.Contains("|c"))
    output = output.Remove(output.IndexOf("|c"), 10);
// output = "Save Code = AGQg R9$# 4fR"
```

I like this much more than using Regexes just because it's so much more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 = "|c001177ffSave Code =|r |cff00AA00A|cff00AA00G|cff00AA00Q|cffff69b4g|r |cff00AA00R|cff40e0d09|cffffff00$|cffffff00#|r |cff40e0d04|cffff69b4f|cff00AA00R"
var str2 = Regex.Replace(str,@"\|(r|[a-zA-Z0-9]{9})","") //"Save Code = AGQg R9$# 4fR"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer re: escaping the "pipe" character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187968/2483451), you're starting your regex with the caret (`^`) character.  This matches the beginning of a line.

A correct regex would be:

```
\|c[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should match all of the characters you want to remove:

```
([|]c([0-9]|[a-f]|[A-F]){8})|[|]r
```

Here's the breakdown...

The vertical pipe is an OR marker, so to search for it, place it in square brackets [ and ].

The parenthesis makes a set.  So you're searching for ([|]c([0-9]|[a-f]|[A-F]){8}) OR [|]r which is all of your color codes OR |r.

Breakdown of the color codes is the set that begins with |c and is followed by the set of exactly 8 characters that can be 0 though 9 or a through f or A through F.

I tested it at RegexPal.com.