# Regex (\w)\1{4,} what does it mean python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I study Regex from last 5 days and still don't get it. It seems Regex is not possible to understand.

If (\w) mean every alphanumeric character in groups, \1 mean group number 1 and {4,} mean match it 4 or more times, how Regex (\w)\1{4,} in string "aa bbbb abcdefg ccccc 111121111 999999999" match to "ccccc"? Can someone explain me it? For me with (\w)\1 the answer should be just second "a". Cant find the answer anywhere.

Comment: The pattern `(\w)\1{4,}` repeats 4 or more times the value captured in group 1. Number 4 is the minimum part of the quantifier, so it can not match the `aa ` at the start.

Comment: so in my opinion it should be 'aaaa' and it is not

Comment: There is no `aaaaa` in the string. See https://regex101.com/r/tjUwn1/1 Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880127/have-trouble-understanding-capturing-groups-and-back-references and for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032914/what-do-comma-separated-numbers-in-curly-braces-at-the-end-of-a-regex-mean

Comment: You literally just (correctly) explained what the regex pattern does. How do you expect it to match `aa`? You need at least `aaaaa`. Yes, `(\w)\1` should match `aa`, but your pattern is _**not**_ `(\w)\1`. It's `(\w)\1{4,}`.

Comment: Im using regex101. But cant understand what it is saying. Thats why i wrote here.

Answer (score -1):

This regex just means "match a word character(`(\w)`), then match it again (`\1`) 4+ times (`{4,}`)", or just "match the same word character 5+ times, but only capture one character". For instance, `ccccc` matches because first `(\w)` matches the first "c", then `\1{4,}` matches 4+ of the first capture group, or 4+ "c"s.

Comment: its to hard for me to understand. Still dont know whats going on there

Comment: Ah i see. For first time it takes "a" and trying to match it 4 times and it doesnt match, "b"same, and came to "c" and it matched 5 times?

Comment: Yes. Additionally, it will also match for example "dddddddddddd".

Comment: Thank you, probably I get it, but it is still abstraction for me.