# Interpretation of comma in regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to know how comma is interpreted in regular expression. Did some research on net and want to validate my understanding as explained in fol snippet:-

```
{a,b}*  can mean {a+b}* and matches a,aa,b,bb,ab,abbb,aaab,ababab etc
similarly, {a,aba} would match either a or aba
```

Or is there any other explanation

Comment: You cold try [using `{a,b}*`](https://regex101.com/r/0V5Ei1/1) and see if your understanding is is correct

Comment: Maybe you refer to regular languages, not specifically to `regex`?

Comment: I agree with @trincot, it sounds like you aren't talking about `regex`

Comment: awesome. today i learnt there is difference between regular language and regex. Pl mention difference in answer concisely and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to refer to regular expressions in *formal language theory*. In computer programming we use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) as a very particular implementation of a regular expression grammar and syntax that evolved to  include operations that do not belong to the theoretical concept of regular expressions (cf. [regular-language](/questions/tagged/regular-language)).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns) notes:

> The phrase *regular expressions*, or *regexes*, is often used to mean the specific, standard textual syntax for representing patterns for matching text, as distinct from the mathematical notation...

Pure regular expressions just have three operators:

- Concatenation
- Alternation
- Kleene closure

The syntax used for these operators can differ. For example, all of the following would mean the same, but with different syntax rules:

- `(a+b)c*`
- `(a|b)c*`
- `{a,b}c*`

Personally, I think the braces are a bad choice, because they are used to denote the *alphabet* of the regular language, i.e. the [set of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(formal_languages)) on which it operates, and in `regex` they are used [as a quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17032914/5459839) to limit how many times the preceding pattern can repeat.

As to your specific question:

> how comma is interpreted

It is the *alternation* operator. More often `+` is used for this operator in formal language discussions, while in computer language the symbol `|` is used for it.